# Bypassing escaping string and prepared statements in php

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I'm working on my bachelor thesis about security of sql databases. I was using sqlmap to check vulnerable sql queries. Is there up to date sql injection that can bypass escaping string done with functions mysqli_real_escape_string or bypass prepared statement ?

I was using sqlmap to check it but it couldn't inject prepared or escaped queries

Comment: Speaking of escaping *string*, there is none. However, in case one being foolish enough trying to escape any other query part, it would be a straight up SQL injection

Comment: It's important to note that using `mysqli_real_escape_string` and prepared statements are both effective measures to prevent SQL injection attacks. However, there is always a possibility of vulnerabilities depending on how the code is written and implemented.

Comment: @kampit mysqli_real_escape_string BY NO MEANS even REMOTELY related to " measures to prevent SQL injection attacks". PLEASE do not spread that nasty rumor

Comment: It's not that `mysqli_real_escape_string` is inherently bad, but that it's just insufficient. People do not know or care to use it properly. It's really cumbersome and if the code is not written properly, you can still break the SQL.

Comment: You can't inject prepared queries because by design they are invulnerable to SQL injection. However, a bad programmer can still make an SQL injection vulnerability even with prepared statements. SQL injection isn't about the technology but about bad coders.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's too general to say it's not at all safe. Next may concern sanitize, restrict access, privilege principle, WAF & more

Comment: Your question has an analogy: "*I heard guns kill people. I sat in front of a loaded gun for 24h and it hasn't killed anyone. Are guns still responsible for human deaths?*"

Comment: @YourCommonSense. However, there is always a possibility of vulnerabilities depending on how the code is written and implemented.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Let's not hijack this question's comments to discuss terminology, please.

Comment: It is not a "terminology" but a wild superstition that plagued poor PHP folks for decades. It's even relevant to the question, because it is not 100% clear whether the OP understands what this function's purpose is. But well, let's don't.